# How to merge 2 huge SQL Server tables without a lot of disk space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, ssis, sql-update

I have 2 tables. Here is my merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO Transactions_Raw AS Target
USING Four_Fields AS Source
ON
    Target.PI = Source.PI AND
    Target.TIME_STAMP = Source.TIME_STAMP AND
    Target.STS = Source.STS
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
    Target.FROM_APP_A = Source.FROM_APP_A,
    Target.TO_APP_A = Source.TO_APP_A,
    Target.FROM_APP_B = Source.FROM_APP_B,
    Target.TO_APP_B = Source.TO_APP_B;
```

Both tables have around 77 million rows to them.

When I run this command, it fails due to tempdb growing and running out of disk space. I cannot get more space.

I tried running it as an update statement and it still failed.

I even tried using SSIS, sort and merge-join transformations from these 2 source tables into a 3rd empty table, left join on transactions_raw... It failed and crashed the server requiring a reboot.

I am thinking I need to run it in batches of 100,000 rows or something? How would I do that? Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could do it in a loop/batch and would have to use one of the tables ID's as the looping variable, then do your merge statement and add where Transaction_Raw ID Between x (this is variable in looping) x + 1000

Comment: Why not an update using a join? Would be a lot simpler than a MERGE. But with 77 million rows you probably need to use batching.

Answer (score 0):

-- this is code example doing a loop a bit more explained what I said in comments for an example you just have to plug in your code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @PerBatchCount as int
DECLARE @MAXID as bigint
DECLARE @WorkingOnID as bigint

Set @PerBatchCount = 1000

--Find range of IDs to process
SELECT @WorkingOnID = MIN(ID), @MAXID = MAX(ID)
FROM MasterTableYouAreWorkingOn


WHILE @WorkingOnID <= @MAXID
    BEGIN 
        -- do an update on all the ones that exist in the offer table NOW
        --MergeStatementHere with adding the where below for ID
        WHERE ID BETWEEN @WorkingOnID AND (@WorkingOnID + @PerBatchCount -1)

    -- if the loop runs too much data you may need to add this to delay for your log to have time to ship/empty out     
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' -- wait 10 seconds

    set @WorkingOnID = @WorkingOnID + @PerBatchCount  

END
```

Comment: Sorry I cleaned up some other code to provide the example and the DT was an alias to a table that I removed but I missed removing the alias (I removed them from above)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: if you want to use any framework to do this job.

> spring-batch is a good choice to perform this task.

Even though it involves some coding, it will be helpful in transferring the data seemless and consistent way.

You can choose the row size(100,000) you want to transfer at a time.

> Any failures while inserting the data would be limited to set of
>   rows (100,000). So you need to deal with less data and insert only
>   this delta data after fixing it. Correct data can be inserted
>   successfully. This whole set of control will be provided by using
>   spring-batch.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer BCP for such operations on huge tables.

If that query (make sure it repeats the structure of Target table)

```
SELECT 
  Target.ID,
  Target.TIME_STAMP,
  Target.STS,
  ISNULL(Source.FROM_APP_A, Target.FROM_APP_A) AS FROM_APP_A,
  ISNULL(Source.TO_APP_A , Target.TO_APP_A) AS TO_APP_A,
  ISNULL(Source.FROM_APP_B, Target.FROM_APP_B) AS FROM_APP_B,
  ISNULL(Source.TO_APP_B , Target.TO_APP_B) AS TO_APP_B
   FROM Database.dbo.Transactions_Raw AS Target
  LEFT JOIN  Database.dbo.Four_Fields AS Source
   ON Target.ID = Source.ID AND
    Target.TIME_STAMP = Source.TIME_STAMP AND
    Target.STS = Source.STS*
```

won't overflow your TempDB, you can use it to export data into the file using something like

```
bcp "query_here" queryout D:\Data.dat -S server -Uuser -k -n
```

Later import data in a new table using something like

```
bcp Database.dbo.NewTable in D:\Data.dat -S server -Uuser -n -k -b 100000 -h TABLOCK
```